# asp.net, c# autocomplete extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

1) I have a textbox to enter initial letters of the item and,
2) a search button on click of which a listbox appears showing the matching searches. 
3) I want to convert this into autocomplete extender and want to remove the listbox.
Following is my code which I have tried:

```
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public List<string> OnSearchEntity(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        List<string> outsideEntities = new List<string>();
        DataTable dtOutsideEntity = COIOrganizationCollection.GetOrganizations(prefixText);

        for (int i = 0; i < dtOutsideEntity.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            outsideEntities.Add(dtOutsideEntity.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
        }
        return outsideEntities;
    }
```

but it is showing an error:

Error   82  No overload for 'OnSearchEntity' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler'

I have also tried changing the parameters, viz.

```
    public List<string> OnSearchEntity(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> outsideEntities = new List<string>();
 DataTable dtOutsideEntity =COIOrganizationCollection.GetOrganizations(entityName.Text.Trim());

        for (int i = 0; i < dtOutsideEntity.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            outsideEntities.Add(dtOutsideEntity.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
        }
        return outsideEntities;
    }
```

it again gives an error:
Error   83  'System.Collections.Generic.List  has the wrong return type

kindly help, or suggest the right way for this conversion.

Comment: control event has void return type,same lines of code in event can execute many times ,you can add parameters in it using lambda expression

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass List of outsideEntities into the arguments using Lambda expression ,It will get changed automatically once event is fired. No need to return this list .
You can use this example and change it for your event

```
    lnkSynEvent.Click += 
               new EventHandler((s,e)=>lnkSynEvent_Click(s, e, your_parameter));
```

Be careful same lines may get excecuted manytimes in event , even the event is fired just once

Comment: this event doesn't have any definition for "click"

Comment: that is just example ..You have to use it as your requirement
forexample Image.ImageClick+=new ImageClickEventHandler((s,e)=>OnSearchEntity(s,e,outsideEntities)

Answer (score 0):

the error was because :
i had used image button on click event, and for the same function i was using it for two different type of parameters,viz.

**onsearch(sender, eventargs e)**,
and **onsearch(string a, int count)**

in my case i could remove the button since i was converting it to autocomplete extender so search button was not required.

thank you for the help!